# Merging multi-polygons gives me error in shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I am trying to merge a bunch of either polygons or multipolygons by the merge_multi_polygons function in shapely, I am using my below code inside Spark

```
        elems=row['_c0']
        area_multipolygons=[]
        for y in elems:
            json_polygon=[]
            searchObj = re.finditer( r'[(]{1}([^()]*)[)]{1}', y)
            for i in searchObj:
                if i:
                    st_polygon= i.group(1)
                    list_polygon=[float(i) for i in st_polygon.split()]
                    json_loop=list(zip(list_polygon[::2], list_polygon[1::2]))
                    json_polygon.append(json_loop)

            forest_area_multipolygon=[json_polygon] 
            area_multipolygons.append(forest_area_multipolygon)

        merged_parttion_polygon=merge_multi_polygons(*area_multipolygons)
```

I get below error on some of my data

```
 File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\util.py", line 55, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 147, in <lambda>
    udf_calculate_intersection=udf(lambda x: calculate_intersection(x), FloatType())
  File "main.py", line 138, in calculate_intersection
    merged_parttion_polygon=merge_multi_polygons(*area_multipolygons)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\eclipse-workspace\EliizaTest\mahdi\polygon_utils.py", line 75, in merge_multi_polygons
    res = [to_polygon(union)]
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\eclipse-workspace\EliizaTest\mahdi\polygon_utils.py", line 47, in to_polygon
    e = coords(polygon_shape.exterior)
AttributeError: 'GeometryCollection' object has no attribute 'exterior'
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge multi polygons` is not a shapely function to my knowledge. Try cascaded union https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union .